# MongoDB Schema - error calling createIndex() for setting expireAt

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wrote my Schema but when I run my Node.js server the following error is showing:

> MySchema.createIndex is not a function

I'm using it for setting the expireAt of the record. This is my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var config = require('../../config.js');

var tc = new Date();
var te = tc.setSeconds(tc.getSeconds + config.EXPIRE_TOKEN_TIME.ROOM_TOKEN);

var MySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    guide: String,
    leader: String,
    partecipants_counter : { type: Number, default: 0},
    event_counter : { type: Number, default: 0},
    createAt: { type: Date, default: tc},
    expireAt: { type: Date, default: te},
    partecipants: [],
    events : [ {
            id : Number,
            data: String,
            user: String
            } ]
});

MySchema.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 180 } );

module.exports = mongoose.model(config.DATA_TYPE.ROOM, MySchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
MySchema.index( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 180 } );
```

**More generic example:-**

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});

animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
```

Comment: Well, that error seems to be not present now but I can't go forward becausethere is a casting of my variables `tc` and `te` which fails... By using `Date.now` there is no casting but the `.setSeconds` function is not available.

Comment: expireAt wants a Date in ms (Date.now) or an Object (new Date()) ?

Comment: I just miss () in get Seconds :). Thanks